# does python ctypes supports size-0 array?

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

i have a struct with array[0] inside it.i wonder how can i represent it with ctypes? or if ctypes does not supprt it, are there any other solutions? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can represent a struct like this:

```
struct Test
{
    int size;
    char arr[0];
};
```

As:

```
class Test(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('size',ctypes.c_int),
                ('arr',ctypes.c_byte*0)]
```

But to access the field, you'll need to cast it to a pointer.  Assume `t` is of type `ctypes.POINTER(Test)`:

```
arr = ctypes.cast(t.contents.arr,POINTER(c_byte))
for i in range(t.contents.size):
    print(arr[i])
```

**Tested Windows example**

x.h

```
#ifdef TESTAPI_EXPORTS
#define TESTAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TESTAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

struct Test
{
    int size;
    int arr[0];
};

TESTAPI struct Test* Test_alloc(int size);
TESTAPI void Test_free(struct Test* test);
```

x.c (Compile with "cl /LD x.c")

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TESTAPI_EXPORTS
#include "x.h"

struct Test* Test_alloc(int size)
{
    struct Test* t = malloc(sizeof(struct Test) + size * sizeof(int));
    if(t != NULL)
    {
        int i;
        t->size = size;
        for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            t->arr[i] = i*1000+i;
    }
    return t;
}

void Test_free(struct Test* test)
{
    free(test);
}
```

x.py

```
from ctypes import *

class Test(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('size',c_int),
                ('arr',c_int*0)]

dll = CDLL('x')

Test_alloc = dll.Test_alloc
Test_alloc.argtypes = [c_int]
Test_alloc.restype = POINTER(Test)

Test_free = dll.Test_free
Test_free.argtypes = [POINTER(Test)]
Test_free.restype = None

t = Test_alloc(10)
print(t.contents.size)
arr = cast(t.contents.arr,POINTER(c_int))
for i in range(t.contents.size):
    print(arr[i])
Test_free(t)
```

Output

```
10
0
1001
2002
3003
4004
5005
6006
7007
8008
9009
```

Comment: It's better to cast to an actual array, e.g. `arr = cast(t[0].arr, POINTER(c_int * t[0].size))[0]`. An array is iterable, plus you don't have to worry about passing around the array and the size together, or risk segfaulting if pointer dereferencing goes out of bounds.

Comment: Another way to get this result is `arr = (c_int * t[0].size).from_address(addressof(t[0].arr))`. This way is probably more efficient since `cast` is implemented as a foreign function call.

Comment: What I like to do in cases like this is make the field private, e.g. named `_arr`, and add a public `property` that accesses the field as an array of the given `size`.

Comment: I tried it and worked well. as @eryksun suggested, I made a public method to access it.  Thank you all for your help