# How do I get back original buffer from a ctypes.Structure?

Tags: python, ctypes

`msg` is created using extra bytes i.e. more than `sizeof(Message)`

```
from ctypes import *

class Message(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("length",  c_ushort),
                ("version", c_ubyte),
                ("type",    c_ubyte),
                ("index",   c_int),
                ("flags",   c_int),
    ]

msg = Message.from_buffer(bytearray.fromhex('1000 05 06 01000000 deadbeef cccccccc'))
```

But, `bytes(msg)` just returns `sizeof(Message)` bytes.

```
>>> bytes(msg).hex()
'1000050601000000deadbeef'
```

How do I retrieve the original bytearray from `msg`? Do I need to make a more elaborate `Message` class that overrides `__bytes__`, `from_buffer` etc.?

Comment: Isn't Structure.from_buffer() ignoring extra space? (The original bytearray could be kept around & accessed separately?)

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It seems wrong. Why not simply use the buffer?

Comment: @CristiFati because I would rather have a single abstraction that includes all the data instead of having to deal with Message and bytearray instances separately.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "Message" is a header and the total size in `length` is the header size plus the variable data after the header.  Define the header, then make a factory function that dynamically creates a structure with a header and an array of the appropriate size:

```
from ctypes import *

class Header(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("length", c_ushort),
                ("version", c_ubyte),
                ("type", c_ubyte),
                ("index", c_int),
                ("flags", c_int)]

def make_msg(hexstring):

    buf = bytearray.fromhex(hexstring)
    datalen = len(buf) - sizeof(Header)

    class Message(Structure):
        _fields_ = [("header", Header),
                    ("data", c_char * datalen)]

    return Message.from_buffer(buf)

msg = make_msg('1000 05 06 01000000 deadbeef cccccccc')
print(msg.header.length)
print(msg.data)
```

Output:

```
16
b'\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc'
```

Comment: Now that I understand that you have a variable-sized buffer with a header, see this answer of mine from a few days ago.  Add a zero-sized array member to the end of your structure and resize it once you know the length: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63000883/235698

Comment: @sigjuice Edited my answer based on your code and my answer linked above.

Comment: I have several different types of Headers.  I made a crude subclass of ctypes.Structure that remembers the original buf.